# For-loop for multiple time series - cointegration test

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to loop multiple ADF-tests on a pair of time series, I want to test for co-integration of each pair. I have a large data set with a lot of different variables which is cumbersome to do manually. As an example, I have:

```
a <- c(10, 8, 7, 10, 8, 9, 7)
b <- c(11, 12, 9, 7, 8, 9, 10)
c <- c(12, 11, 9, 10, 13, 11, 9)

train <- cbind(a, b, c)
train <- as.ts(train)

test1 <- lm(a ~ b, data = train)
test2 <- lm(a ~ c, data = train)
test3 <- lm(b ~ a, data = train)
test4 <- lm(b ~ c, data = train)
test5 <- lm(c ~ a, data = train)
test6 <- lm(c ~ b, data = train)

test7 <- list(test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6)

adf.test(test7[[1]]$residuals)
adf.test(test7[[2]]$residuals)
adf.test(test7[[3]]$residuals)
adf.test(test7[[4]]$residuals)
adf.test(test7[[5]]$residuals)
adf.test(test7[[6]]$residuals)
```

Instead of doing each combination manually and test it, how could I loop for all possible combinations as above? I have over 100 variables, not 3 as in the example above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expand.grid()` to get the combination and create the formula. i.e.,

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, c(subset(expand.grid(letters[1:3], letters[1:3]), Var1 != Var2), sep = ' ~ '))

[1] "b ~ a" "c ~ a" "a ~ b" "c ~ b" "a ~ c" "b ~ c"
```

From there you can loop and apply `lm()`, i.e.

```
sapply(v1, function(i)lm(as.formula(i), data = train))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this code to my dataset (not named a, b, c, etc.):

test <- do.call(paste, c(subset(expand.grid(colnames(df), colnames(df)), Var1 != Var2), sep = ' ~ '))

and this works, but when I try the sapply function: 

test8 <- sapply(test, function(i)lm(i, data = df))

I get the following error message: 

"Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(v) <- "double" :
 Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'"

Comment: I dont fully understand how I can loop the ADF-tests

Comment: I think we need to add `as.formula()`. I edited. Try it and let me know

Comment: I still get the same error when trying to run the code on my data, even though I use as.formula() instead. 

Another problem I noticed, when trying to apply the ADF-test to the above example code: 

v1 <- do.call(paste, c(subset(expand.grid(letters[1:3], letters[1:3]), Var1 != Var2), sep = ' ~ '))

v2 <- sapply(v1, function(i)lm(as.formula(i), data = train))

adf.test(v2["residuals",1]

I get: 

Error in as.vector(x, mode = "double") : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'